# How do you display xterm colors with putty/bash?

Tags: colors, putty, xterm

Putty has this "allow terminal use xterm 256 colour mode" that I'd like to use, but I don't know how. I've been using a `color.sh` script to output echo statements and commands with colors, and I want to do something like that with xterm colors.

```
#!/bin/bash
## Specify color to write in using arguments

function --help {
cat << EOF

ERROR: $0 requires a color argument.

USAGE: Changes the color of the text piped into it.

These color arguments are availabe:

    ARGUMENT    SHORTCUT
    white   ------  w
    red ------  r
    green   ------  g
    yellow  ------  y
    blue    ------  b
    violet  ------  v
    teal    ------  t

    bold    ------  bb

The "bold" argument will modify any color.
Use a max of 2 arguments (one color and bold).

EOF
}

function bold {
# make the color bold
BOLD=1\;
}

function white {
COLOR=1
}

function red {
COLOR=31
}

function green {
COLOR=32
}

function yellow {
COLOR=33
}

function blue {
COLOR=34
}

function violet {
COLOR=35
}

function teal {
COLOR=36
}


## shortcuts
function bb {
bold
}
function w {
white
}
function r {
red
}
function g {
green
}
function y {
yellow
}
function b {
blue
}
function v {
violet
}
function t {
teal
}
function o {
red
bold
}

## Execution

if [ "$#" = 0 ]
then
--help
fi

while (($#));
    do
        $1
        shift
    done

echo -n "["$BOLD""$COLOR"m"
cat
echo -n "[0m"
```

Comment: Did you try the "use system colors" option ? Or maybe you can take a look to "terminal compatibility"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the PuTTY user manual this should be [enabled by default](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-xtermcolour):

> If you have an application which is supposed to use 256-colour mode and it isn't working, you may find you need to tell your server that your terminal supports 256 colours. On Unix, you do this by ensuring that the setting of TERM describes a 256-colour-capable terminal. You can check this using a command such as `infocmp`:
>
> ```
> $ infocmp | grep colors
>         colors#256, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#256,
> ```
>
> If you do not see `colors#256` in the output, you may need to change your terminal setting. On modern Linux machines, you could try `xterm-256color`.

If you are looking to use 256 colours in a specific application, like Vim or Emacs, there are separate guides for how to achieve that:

- Vim: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_color_schemes_with_Putty
- Emacs: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PuTTY#toc2

Comment: A simpler way to get the number of available colors for the current $TERM value is `tput colors`.

Comment: You can also try to configure Putty's terminal type (`Connection->Data->Terminal-type string`) to `putty-256color` which may be recognized by your system.

Answer (score 22):

For me, I had to go into settings and set the terminal type. **Settings** -> **Connection** > **Data** > **Terminal-type** change to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: What @directedition said is nearly correct but setting the TERM value to putty-256color is more accurate if that is supported. Settings -> Connection > Data > Terminal-type change to putty-256color. I don't have comment permission. See this answer for more info: https://superuser.com/a/1069018/1030245

Comment: `xterm-256color` worked good for me, while `putty-256color` caused errors when using arrows or `less` tool. Connecting to Ubuntu 19

Comment: This answer seems to be better suited for 2020's Ubuntu Installations and Windows Putty users

Answer (score 2):

Click on the System menu at the upper left corner of the PuTTY window.

Select Change Settings > Window > Colours.
In the box that says "Select a colour to adjust", choose ANSI Blue and click the Modify Button.
Slide the black arrow on the right up until you see a lighter shade of blue that you like.
Click OK.
Perform the same steps for ANSI Blue Bold so you can have a perceptible difference between the two.
When you're finished, click Apply.